# Laravel giving invalid view error for mail

Tags: laravel, email, events

I'm new to Laravel. I wanted to send a mail to users for every time they login. I wrote the authentication logic already.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Users;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Events\Login;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('users.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            event(new Login(auth()->user()));
            return redirect()->intended(route('homepage'));
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Username/Password Combo Wrong!');
        }

    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login-form');
    }
}
```

I wrote an event for this

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\User;

class Login
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }



    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

This is the event listener

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use App\Mail\UserLoggedIn;

class SendLoginNotification
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        Mail::send($event)->send(new UserLoggedIn($event));
    }
}
```

I created a mail class

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class UserLoggedIn extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@mail.com')->view('emails.users.loggedin');
    }
}
```

I then created the view for the mail in resources/views/emails/users/loggedin.blade.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Logged In</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{$user->name}} Logged in
</body>
</html>
```

But when i run try to run the login, i get an error saying invalid view

Comment: Just an FYI, Laravel already has a login `event` (`Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login`). As well, it might be easier to use Notifications rather than Mail.

Comment: where is your homepage route??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I've noticed. Currently, you're:

- calling `send` twice in your `SendLoginNotification` (and you're passing the `Event` instead of a mailable to one of them)
- not specifying who to send the mail to
- also passing the `$event` to the mailable rather than the `User`

Change:

```
Mail::send($event)->send(new UserLoggedIn($event));
```

To:

```
Mail::to($event->user)->send(new UserLoggedIn($event->user)); //notice the "user" property.
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't pass any variable containing user info.

```
public function build()
{
    $user=User::find(1);
    return $this->from('test@mail.com')->view('emails.users.loggedin',compact('user'));
}
```